# Is there any leetcode like site where salesforce developers can practice coding?

Tags: apex

Could you please suggest on how to sharpen coding skills in salesforce.

Comment: You do this using [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) playgrounds or a free developer org.

Comment: you can use https://www.apexsandbox.io/ it has pretty good exercises for apex I'm not sure is 100% leetcode style but really helps to improve on apex.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a site. Most of your skill development in this sphere is going to be self-directed.

Beyond https://trailhead.salesforce.com which likely contains intermediate/advanced level trails and modules that you haven't gone through yet, some good resources are:

- Recorded sessions from past years of Dreamforce (not counting the keynote sessions, which I've always found have no real substance to them)
- Official [developer blogs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs) and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/@SalesforceDevs/videos)
- Trawling this site for questions/problems you find interesting and trying to solve the issue yourself (solve it on your own first, then compare to existing solutions. Compare and contrast the approaches taken)

On the Dreamforce sessions front, it seems that Salesforce has unfortunately maimed the recorded sessions, tossed them into a cellar, and locked the door. It looks like [Salesforce plus](https://www.salesforce.com/plus) (launched in 2021) is the current home of recorded sessions, but it doesn't appear to have much in the way of value. The 6 video developer focused playlist for Dreamforce 2023 starts off with a keynote, followed by a recap of the keynote, a plug for Salesforce's brand of AI, and a demo/pitch for Mulesoft. You may still be able to find some useful videos through https://www.salesforce.com/video/# (my disdain for JS front-ends that hide state so it's impossible to deep link to anything continues to grow).